# copy/paste image in rich editor

Tags: image, jsf-2, richfaces, rich-text-editor

I'm using Rich-faces editor in my application, while using the application through Firefox 4.0.1, I realized that i can copy/paste image into the editor. The pasted image is base64 encoded.
But the problem here is that image(along with the other contents of editor) gets hidden when the page is submitted, but available in the variable bound to that value of editor.
How to avoid the image and text in the editor from vanishing. If a small image is copied to the editor it's retained even after the form is submitted. Help please